# Image gets deleted from table after page refresh, also clicking on it does not trigger a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, html-table

I have a table, and everytime the user clicks the add button it adds a new row, with 4 `<td>` elements, three of which are input elements, the last is a little button. clicking the add button works perfectly, but whenever I click the little button, nothing happens. It does not trigger a function, and when I refresh the page, the button, but not the input elements, disappears. Here's the ajax that adds the table row:

```
    var new_period = $("<tr data-pid='" + period.id + "' class='period'>" +
    "<td>Name:</td><td><input class='period_name' type='text'></td>" +
    "<td>Start:</td><td><input class='period_start' type='text'></td>" +
    "<td>End:</td><td><input class='period_end' type='text'></td>" + 
    "<td><a id='remove_periods_btn' href = '#'><img src='/img/x.png'></a></td>" +
    "</tr>");
```

Here's my jQuery function that should trigger when clicking the little button:

```
    $("#remove_periods_btn").click(function(e) {
        alert("Working");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: An id has to be unique inside of one document. And also, jQuery’s .click only binds events to elements already existing in the DOM – if you are adding elements later, you have to use `.on`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @CBroe `.on()` has nothing to do with this issue, you can attach an event handler any way you want (bind/live/click/ready), the element just has to exist.

Comment: Yes, but using `.on` (as a replacement for deprecated `.live`) the elements _don’t_ have to exist already. What you are doing in your answer, is what I actually meant :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', "#remove_periods_btn", function(e) {
    alert("Working");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You are only attaching your event handler to elements that are currently in the DOM; if they are added through ajax, you can attach an event handler to the document object and check of the target is your element.

A "worse" solution (essentially what jQuery does behind the scenes for the above code)

```
$(document).click(function(eventObject){
    if (eventObject.target.id === 'remove_periods_btn') {
        alert("Working");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: That fixes half my problem. Thanks. :D (No sarcasm)